# Cannot Read Properties of Undefined (reading 'buildClient')

Tags: node.js, shopify, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to import the unoptimized version of the shopify-buy SDK into a node/svelte project. I am encountering an issue with initializing the client.

The error is "Cannot Read Properties of Undefined (reading 'buildClient')".

This is the initialization code:

```
import Client from 'shopify-buy/index.unoptimized.umd';

const domain = 'xxx';
const storefrontAccessToken = 'xxx';

const client = Client.buildClient({
  domain: domain,
  storefrontAccessToken: storefrontAccessToken
});

const productsQuery = Client.graphQLClient.query((root) => {
  root.addConnection('products', {args: {first: 10}}, (product) => {
    product.add('tags');
  });
});


Client.graphQLClient.send(productsQuery).then(({model, data}) => {
  console.log(model);
});
```

Comment: I'd don't get that error (nodejs:v20.3.0 using shopify-buy: "2.19.0") but the `Client.graphQLClient` should be `client.graphQLClient` (lower case c)